# Idiomatic way to extract matches from rust Regex?

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm learning rust and doing an exercise where to parse a particular SGML document.
Each line in a document can be either an opening tag "" , a closing tag "" or a scalar: " Val".
I'm using a regex with named capture groups to detect and extract, and would like to return an enum afterwards.

I came up with the following code, but it feels overly verbose and un-idiomatic, so I'm seeking feedback, particularly on the *extract_tag_from_line_match* function

```rust
    use regex::Captures;
    use regex::Regex;

    struct LineParseError;
    enum Tag {
        Open(String),
        Close(String),
        Scalar(String, String),
    }
    fn extract_line_tag(line: &str) -> Result<Tag, LineParseError> {
        let reg: Regex = Regex::new(r"<((?P<close>/))|((?P<open>.+)>(?P<value>.+)?)").unwrap();

        let capture = reg.captures(line);
        match capture {
            None => Err(LineParseError),
            Some(cap) => Ok(extract_tag_from_line_match(cap)),
        }
    }

    fn extract_tag_from_line_match(capture: Captures) -> Tag {
        let close = capture.name("close");
        let open = capture.name("open");
        let value = capture.name("value");

        let scalar = open.zip(value);
        if (scalar.is_some()) {
            let (o, v) = scalar.unwrap();
            return Tag::Scalar(String::from(o.as_str()), String::from(v.as_str()));
        } else if close.is_some() {
            let c = close.unwrap();
            return Tag::Close(String::from(c.as_str()));
        } else {
            let v = open.unwrap();
            return Tag::Open(String::from(v.as_str()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to the Rust community.

### Correctness

Are you sure the code is correct? The regex looks odd, but ok. It seems that `Tag::Close` does not carry any meaningful info, even though it contains a String.

### Manual

Be sure to read up on `if let` statements. They are useful for concise and idiomatic code. Here, catch some reading material:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rust-if-let-operator/
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html

### Nitpicks

- I changed `String::from` to `.to_string()`.
- I believe you confused `v` with `o` in the last branch.
- Don't use single letter variable names too often. (I didn't change this below.)
- The double parenthesis around `?P<close>/` is unnecessary - single is enough.

### Code

```rust
use regex::Captures;
use regex::Regex;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct LineParseError;
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Tag {
    Open(String),
    Close(String),
    Scalar(String, String),
}
fn extract_line_tag(line: &str) -> Result<Tag, LineParseError> {
    let reg: Regex = Regex::new(r"<((?P<close>/))|((?P<open>.+)>(?P<value>.+)?)").unwrap();

    let capture = reg.captures(line);
    match capture {
        None => Err(LineParseError),
        Some(cap) => Ok(extract_tag_from_line_match(cap)),
    }
}

fn extract_tag_from_line_match(capture: Captures) -> Tag {
    let close = capture.name("close");
    let open = capture.name("open");
    let value = capture.name("value");

    let scalar = open.zip(value);
    if let Some((o, v)) = scalar {
        return Tag::Scalar(o.as_str().to_string(), v.as_str().to_string());
    } else if let Some(c) = close {
        return Tag::Close(c.as_str().to_string());
    } else if let Some(o) = open {
        return Tag::Open(o.as_str().to_string());
    } else {
        unreachable!();
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", extract_line_tag("<val>"));
    println!("{:?}", extract_line_tag("</val>"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And double thanks for the super fast help.
I have a question about to_string() . 

Being lazy, would it be idiomatic to add a trait to the regex::Match to_string() so that I wouldn't have to write out to_str().to_string() ?

Comment: @user38310 Yes, I believe it would be idiomatic to do that. But don't be so lazy, keep in mind the code is fine as it is :) Happy to help.

Comment: @user38310 the double parenthesis around `?P<close>/` is unnecessary - single is enough.

Comment: Instead of zipping/unwrapping, you can match directly:

```
match (open, value, close) {
    (Some(o), Some(v), _) => { ... }
    ... and so on
```

I think one letter names are perfectly fine if they are short lived. It's all about readability *in context*